# How to avoid generating database table everytime

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I am using MVC 3. I use Model first approach.

I created the Product Entity, in model folder. Which contains

```
ProductID
Name ---properties.
```

then, I create the SQL table from that model,It generates SQL table perfectly. 
(I right click on model image and selects the option 'Generate database from model...' 
then SQL window pop ups which contains all the DB scripts and I execute it.)

Now problem comes when, If I want to make changes in that model. 
I have to recreate the table each time,so my data get lost.
whether, I have to generate SQL table every time when I make change in model?

How to avoid it?

Comment: i don't think so that their is the way to prevent data being lose when recreating the database on model changes in mvc 3 . in mvc4 they have handle this by the new feature database migration which can help u but that is mvc4.

Comment: @mazharkaunainbaig Database migrations have nothing to do with MVC 4. It is a feature of Entity Framework.

Comment: ok my mistake yes it is the part of entity framework

Comment: yes he can use that version with mvc 3 as well if he likes

Comment: So what should I update ? MVC 3 to MVC 4 or Entity Framework ?